# Strange Eloquent Behavior: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object while Object exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this function that returns a value in the DB:

```
public function getMetaValue($key)
```

I then created a function to read a data in the DB based off of the `getMetaValue`:

```
public function getFeatureByMeta($estate, $type)
{
    $metaId  = (int) $estate->getMetaValue($type);
    $feature = Feature::where('id', $metaId)->first();
    return $feature->name;
}
```

If I now return:

```
$this->getFeatureByMeta($estate, 'stato_immobile')
```

It throws

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object.

While if I dump-die the same exact thing it dumps the correct result:

```
dd($this->getFeatureByMeta($estate, 'stato_immobile')); 
//Returns "Nuovo / In costruzione" which is the DB data `name` I need
```

If I take the function `getFeatureByMeta` and instead of `Feature::where('id', $metaId)` I hardcode the id value, the above error does not show up and I do get the correct item name:

```
public function getFeatureByMeta($estate, $type)
{
    $feature = Feature::where('id', 54)->first();
    return $feature->name;
}
```

And

```
public function getFeatureByMeta($estate, $type)
{
    $metaId  = (int) $estate->getMetaValue($type);
    dd($metaId); //Returns 54
}
```

If I `dd($feature)` I do get the row I'm talking about:

```
App\Feature^ {#904
  //...
  #attributes: array:5 [
    "id" => 57
    "name" => "Da ristrutturare"
    "category" => "stato_immobile"
    "created_at" => "2019-09-16 12:15:13"
    "updated_at" => "2019-09-16 12:15:13"
  ]
  #original: array:5 [
    "id" => 57
    "name" => "Da ristrutturare"
    "category" => "stato_immobile"
    "created_at" => "2019-09-16 12:15:13"
    "updated_at" => "2019-09-16 12:15:13"
  ]
  #changes: []
  //...
}
```

What can be causing this?

I made a video to make it more clear: https://streamable.com/5nsq4

Comment: Check first `$metaId`  returns what.

Comment: `$metaId` returns `54`

Comment: Why not use this if you are finding records by primary key ? `$feature 
 = Feature::find($metaId); return $feature ->name`

Comment: @SalmanZafar I did test it. It gives the same error

Comment: try `dd($feature)` what you get?

Comment: @SalmanZafar with `dd($feature)` I get the eloquent response with the row correctly.

Comment: Can you paste what you get from dd and add it in your question?

Comment: Whats the output of $meta_id ?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I still don't understand the only solution I found is this:

```
public function getFeatureByMeta($estate, $type)
{
    $feature = Feature::find($estate->getMetaValue($type));
    if ($feature) {
        return $feature->name;
    }
}
```

Using the `if` returns the correct name attribute.
If you know why, please comment.

Comment: yup it's because the record you trying to get does not exist

Comment: @Salman why not? It does exist, when I put the IF it shows it exist, so it exist

Comment: Use validation for this so it can be handle automatically